# Why does ForkJoinPool use ThreadPerTaskExecutor?

Tags: java, concurrency, akka, completable-future, forkjoinpool

We run an Akka application in Java on two CPU environment and we observed that with every `tell` a new Thread is initiated instead of taking them from the pool. Akka default dispatcher uses `ForkJoinPool` as the default executor. In `CompletableFuture` code there is following logic:

```
private static final boolean useCommonPool =
        (ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() > 1);


private static final Executor asyncPool = useCommonPool ?
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool() : new ThreadPerTaskExecutor();

static final class ThreadPerTaskExecutor implements Executor {
    public void execute(Runnable r) { new Thread(r).start(); }
}
```

The value of `commonPoolParallelism` comes from `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1` (if JVM property is not specified) - `ForkJoinPool.makeCommonPool()`.

So, in our case - where we have only two CPUs - `ForkJoinPool` is not used at all. It uses `ThreadPerTaskExecutor` instead by default. I know that we can override that (we do and that causes significant performance increase). But that makes me wonder why is that? Why would initiating new thread every time be better than to reuse one from the pool even for one CPU (not mentioning the two)? Why this is the default behavior of `ForkJoinPool`?

Answer (score 0):

If the dispatcher only has one thread and that thread gets blocked, deadlocked, etc., then the entire actor system comes screeching to a halt. With threads per task, that won't happen.

Comment: Thank you for answering. OK, but if by default Akka fork-join-executor has following default properties: `parallelism-min = 8` `parallelism-factor = 3.0` `parallelism-max = 64`. The minimum thread pool size is 8, so I assume it is safe to force it to use that pool? If so, why doesn't Akka set `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` property to be greater than 1?
One CPU (or two in our case) doesn't mean that the dispatcher has only one thread. Why then `commonPoolParallelism` is equal to CPUs - 1?